# entityForName:nil Issue

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to use Core Data to have a user can add a favorite car. The user can pick a make(which is in a separate tableviewcontroller), a model(a textfield), and a year(a textfield). The cars will be shown on a tableview. 
I think I implemented CoreData correctly, but I'm getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext". I don't know what's causing my managedObjectContent to be equal to nil.

Here's the first view. This would display the array of favorite cars.

```
#import "addCar.h"
#import "dreamCar.h"

@implementation dreamCar
@synthesize dreamCarArray;

// Retrieve managed object context and later save the data
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Get cars from database
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Cars"];
    dreamCarArray = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return dreamCarArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"dreamCarCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier    forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell
NSManagedObject *car = [dreamCarArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [car  valueForKey:@"year"],[car valueForKey:@"make"],[car valueForKey:@"model"]]];

 return cell;
}

@end
```

Here's the next view where a user can add a car:

```
#import "addCar.h"
#import "addDreamCarMake.h"

@implementation addCar
@synthesize makeText,modelText,yearText,car;

// Retrieve managed object context and later save the data
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]){
       context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}


-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.modelText.delegate = self;
    self.yearText.delegate = self;

    if(car){
        [self.makeText setText:[car valueForKey:@"make"]];
        [self.modelText setText:[car valueForKey:@"model"]];
        [self.yearText setText:[car valueForKey:@"year"]];
    }
}

//If cancel button is pressed, pop current view from stack
- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// If done button is pressed
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create new Car
    NSManagedObject *newCar = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newCar setValue:makeText forKey:@"make"];
    [newCar setValue:modelText forKey:@"model"];
    [newCar setValue:yearText forKey:@"year"];

    //Pop current view from stack
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Unwind segue from addDreamCarMake
- (IBAction)unwindToListFromAddMake:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
    addDreamCarMake *segue1 = segue.sourceViewController;
    self.makeText.text = segue1.makeName;
}

//Dismiss Keyboard
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self.modelText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.yearText resignFirstResponder];
}

// Dismiss Keyboard
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField){
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

And here is the table view for selecting a make:

```
#import "addCar.h"  
#import "addDreamCarMake.h"

static NSString* makeLabel;

@implementation addDreamCarMake
@synthesize makeName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     //Initial Dictionary
makes = @{ @"A" : @[@"Acura",
                     @"AJS",
                     @"Alfa Romeo",
                     @"Allard",
                     @"Allis Chalmers",
                     @"AM General",
                     @"AMC",
                     @"American",
                     @"American Motors",
                     @"Amphicar",
                     @"Ancarrow",
                     @"Ariel",
                     @"Arnolt",
                     @"Arnolt Bristol",
                     @"Art Work",
                     @"Assembled",
                     @"Aston Martin",
                     @"ASVE",
                     @"ASVE",
                     @"Auburn",
                     @"Audi",
                     @"Aurora",
                     @"Austin",
                     @"Austin-Healey",
                     @"Avanti",],
            @"B" : @[@"Bay Marine",
                     @"Beck",
                     @"Bentley",
                     @"BMW",
                     @"Borum",
                     @"Boss",
                     @"Bourget",
                     @"Brainerd Robbins",
                     @"Bricklin",
                     @"BSA",
                     @"Bugatti",
                     @"Buick",],
            @"C" : @[@"C Boat",
                     @"Cadillac",
                     @"Callaway",
                     @"Caterpillar",
                     @"CAV",
                     @"Century",
                     @"Checker",
                     @"Chevrolet",
                     @"Chris-Craft",
                     @"Chris-Craft/Dewhurst",
                     @"Chrysler",
                     @"Cobra",
                     @"Concept",
                     @"Condor",
                     @"Cord",
                     @"Crosley",
                     @"Cushman",
                     @"Custom",
                     @"Custom Built",
                     @"CZ",],
            @"D" : @[@"Daewoo",
                     @"Daihatsu",
                     @"Daimler",
                     @"Dan Kidney",
                     @"Datsun",
                     @"Delorean",
                     @"DeSoto",
                     @"DeTomaso",
                     @"Diamond",
                     @"Dingle",
                     @"DKW",
                     @"Dodge",
                     @"Dodge ",
                     @"Dry Lakes",
                     @"Duck Boat",
                     @"Duesenberg",
                     @"Dunphy",
                     @"Dyno",],
            @"E" : @[@"Eagle",
                     @"Eddie Trotta",
                     @"Edmunds-Kenyon",
                     @"Edsel",
                     @"Era",
                     @"Essex",
                     @"Evinrude",
                     @"Excalibur",
                     @"Eysink",],
            @"F" : @[@"Factory Five",
                     @"Fantasy",
                     @"Farmall",
                     @"Ferrari",
                     @"Fiat",
                     @"Fleetwood",
                     @"Ford",
                     @"Forsa",
                     @"Framed Art",
                     @"Franklin",
                     @"Frazer",],
            @"G" : @[@"Gar Wood",
                     @"Gar Wood/Michaud",
                     @"Gasoline Pump",
                     @"Geo",
                     @"Glen-L",
                     @"GM",
                     @"GMC",
                     @"Goodhue & Hawkins",
                     @"Graham",
                     @"Greavette",
                     @"Griffith",],
            @"H" : @[@"Hacker",
                     @"Hackercraft",
                     @"Harley-Davidson",
                     @"Hendrick Motorsports",
                     @"Henry J",
                     @"Hickman",
                     @"Higgins ",
                     @"Hillman",
                     @"Hogzoom",
                     @"Holden",
                     @"Honda",
                     @"Horex",
                     @"Hudson",
                     @"Hummer",
                     @"Hunter",
                     @"Hupmobile",
                     @"Hutchinson",
                     @"Hyundai",],
            @"I" : @[@"IH",
                     @"IH Farmall",
                     @"Imperial",
                     @"Indian",
                     @"Indian Lakes",
                     @"Infiniti",
                     @"International",
                     @"Isotta",
                     @"Isuzu",],
            @"J" : @[@"Jaguar",
                     @"JBL",
                     @"Jeep",
                     @"Jensen",
                     @"John Deere",
                     @"Johnson",],
            @"K" : @[@"Kaiser",
                     @"Kia",
                     @"KR Proton",
                     @"Kurtis",],
            @"L" : @[@"Lagonda",
                     @"Lamborghini",
                     @"Land Rover",
                     @"Larson",
                     @"Lasalle",
                     @"Lexus",
                     @"Lighted Sign",
                     @"Lincoln",
                     @"Lola",
                     @"Lotus",
                     @"Lucky Fire",
                     @"Luyere",
                     @"Lyman",],
            @"M" : @[@"MAC Tools",
                     @"Mack",
                     @"Malibu",
                     @"Maserati",
                     @"Massey-Harris",
                     @"Matchless",
                     @"Maxton",
                     @"Mazda",
                     @"McCormick",
                     @"McLaren",
                     @"Memorabilia",
                     @"Mercedes-Benz",
                     @"Mercury",
                     @"Merkur",
                     @"Metal Sign",
                     @"MG",
                     @"Midget",
                     @"Mini",
                     @"Mitsubishi",
                     @"Model",
                     @"Moore",
                     @"Morris",
                     @"Mugen",
                     @"Murray",
                     @"MV Agusta",],
            @"N" : @[@"N.U.T.",
                     @"Nash",
                     @"Neon Sign",
                     @"Nissan",
                     @"Norton",
                     @"NSU",],
            @"O" : @[@"Oakland",
                     @"OCC",
                     @"Oldsmobile",
                     @"Oliver Hart-Parr",],
            @"P" : @[@"Pabst ",
                     @"Pace Arrow",
                     @"Packard",
                     @"Panoz",
                     @"Panther",
                     @"Parts",
                     @"Penn Yan",
                     @"Peugeot",
                     @"Pierce-Arrow",
                     @"Plastic Sign",
                     @"Plymouth",
                     @"Pontiac",
                     @"Porcelain Sign",
                     @"Porsche",
                     @"Prevost",
                     @"Pulse",],
            @"Q" : @[@"Qvale",],
            @"R" : @[@"Racing ",
                     @"Rambler",
                     @"Reading-Standard",
                     @"Renault",
                     @"Reo",
                     @"Replica",
                     @"Replicar",
                     @"Retrovette",
                     @"Revcon",
                     @"Richardson",
                     @"Riva",
                     @"Rolls-Royce",],
            @"S" : @[@"Saab",
                     @"Saleen",
                     @"Saturn",
                     @"Schwinn",
                     @"Scorpion",
                     @"Sea Lyon",
                     @"Seagrave",
                     @"Shay",
                     @"Shelby",
                     @"Shepherd",
                     @"SIMCA",
                     @"Sims",
                     @"Skiff Craft",
                     @"Speed Sport",
                     @"Star",
                     @"Staudacher",
                     @"Sterling",
                     @"Steve McQueen",
                     @"Steyr-Daimler Puch",
                     @"Stone Boatyard",
                     @"Studebaker",
                     @"Subaru",
                     @"Sudlow",
                     @"Sunbeam",
                     @"Sunflower",
                     @"Superformance",
                     @"Suzuki",],
            @"T" : @[@"Thompson",
                     @"Tidal Force",
                     @"Tiffany",
                     @"Tin Sign",
                     @"Toyota",
                     @"Trigre",
                     @"Triumph",
                     @"Truscott",
                     @"TVR",],
            @"V" : @[@"Ventnor",
                     @"Vincent",
                     @"Volkswagen",
                     @"Volvo",],
            @"W" : @[@"Wagner",
                     @"Westcott",
                     @"Whiticar",
                     @"Whizzer",
                     @"Willys",
                     @"Wise & Sons",
                     @"Wise Boat & Bus Works",],
            @"Y" : @[@"Yamaha",
                     @"Yamaha Castrol",
                     @"Yellow Jacket",],
            @"Z" : @[@"Zimmer",
                     @"Zundapp",]},

     makeSectionTitles = [[makes allKeys]   sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [makeSectionTitles count];
}

// Title at each section
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [makeSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}

// Number of rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *sectionTitle = [makeSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionModels = [makes objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionModels count];
}

// Item at each cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addDreamCarMakeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [makeSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionmodels = [makes objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *model = [sectionmodels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = model;

    return cell;
}

// Index on the left side
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return makeSectionTitles;
}

// If back button is pressed, pop current view from stack
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


// Segue
-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender: (UITableViewCell *)sender {

    //Segue back to searchCar
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addMakeCompleted"]) {
    makeLabel = sender.textLabel.text;
    self.makeName = makeLabel;
    }
}
@end
```

Here's the appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface infoMobileAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectModel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end
```

And here's the appdelegate.m

```
#import "infoMobileAppDelegate.h"

@implementation infoMobileAppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

EDIT: 
So in my addCar.h I added a NSManagedObject named car. (strong,nonatomic) 
In my addCar.m, when I debugged through the viewDidLoad, I see it skips through the if(car) statement. I think that's what's causing it to be nil.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.modelText.delegate = self;
    self.yearText.delegate = self;

    if(car){
        [self.makeText setText:[car valueForKey:@"make"]];
        [self.modelText setText:[car valueForKey:@"model"]];
        [self.yearText setText:[car valueForKey:@"year"]];
    }
}
```

EDIT AGAIN: 
Fixed it. My app delegate was missing a few methods. Here were the methods that I had to add in case anyone wants to know:

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    } 

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"coreDataInfoNet" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"coreDataInfoNet.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
} 

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

Comment: Make sure context not nil

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the managedObjectContext method of your view controllers (which btw. looks a bit too complicate). Then step through your program and check why the context is not returned as expected.

Comment: Also I would highly recommend [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) for doing anything more than sneezing at Core Data.

Comment: also make sure you are not misspelling the entity name and debug ur program by setting breakpoints.

Comment: The problem is that your context is nil. Can you post the relevant method from one of your delegates providing the managed object context? And are the delegates weak references?

Comment: And you probably want to change ``performSelector:`` to ``respondsToSelector:``

Comment: Added the App Delegate.

Comment: I would also recommend switching to using queue confinement (and parent child contexts) rather than thread confinement. Thread confinement is the legacy way of doing things, even if it's what Apple's templates and examples still use.

Answer (score -1):

Check your app delegate they require a few core data methods to be present among them and can cause the MOC to be nil if not coded properly)  :

```
  #pragma mark - Core Data stack

  - (void)saveContext{
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You     
  should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful 
  during development. 
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);
     } 
  }
  }



- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext   {

    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
     {
      return __managedObjectContext;       }

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
  if (coordinator != nil)
  {
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    //  printf ("NSPersistent coordinator created");
  }
return __managedObjectContext;

  }

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
  if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
  {
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
      NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"QRData" withExtension:@"momd"];

    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
  return __managedObjectModel;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

  NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]    
URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"QRU.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
{
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

     Typical reasons for an error here include:
     * The persistent store is not accessible;
     * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


     If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

     If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
     * Simply deleting the existing store:
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

     * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

     Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);
  }    

  return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: The application delegate is not required to provide these. Anything can provide a managed object context, persistent store coordinator, or persistent store.

Comment: @quellish you are nuts and you are mean the core data stuff may or may not be located in the app delegate but it is there for a reason and that is to make sure that the MOC can be saved every time the app relinquishes control. - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    
     [self saveContext];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   
    [self saveContext];
}
    ... and how will you ensure that the MOC is saved?

Comment: A managed object context is a scratchpad of changes. When you save it or discard it is up to you (or your user). Your view controllers can easily save in ``viewWillDisappar:``, or listen for the same notifications that the application delegate does. The application delegate is not the only place that you can handle (in your example) ``UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification``.

Comment: But the app delegate is the most convenient place to ensure that it is always saved when control is relinquished particularly if you have core data access all over the place - otherwise you loose your changes, it is a big part of the reason that these codes are part of the template when you start a new app with core data. I'm not saying that what you are saying is not true, I am saying that what you are doing marking down good answers is wrong. Not to mention that you probably spooked the newbie asking this question.

Comment: It's only that way if you are using Core Data incorrectly. You should be creating a new context for each set of changes. The very template you are talking about creates the Core Data stack in the app delegate, but them *passes* the context to the view controller. Apple's own documentation is clear about this: "Nested contexts make it more important than ever that you adopt the “pass the baton” approach of accessing a context (by passing a context from one view controller to the next) rather than retrieving it directly from the app delegate." From "What's new in iOS 5".

Comment: Pass the baton means use one MOC and pass them from view controller to view controller -  this is to ensure that all updates are recorded in sequence and updated appropriately when you save context - also allows you to rollback if you wish. its in the app delegate because it allows you to save the context when the app goes into the background. There is never any mention of creating a new context for each set of changes. It could be possible with simple apps but almost impossible to implement with tabbed apps, where task (and updates) can be left pending in 1 tab while the user switch tabs.

Comment: getting the MOC from the app delegate means you are dealing with the same instance of the MOC, not a new one. Personally I pass the MOC from 1 view controller to the next one because my apps deal with nested data structures and my view controllers follow that data hierarchy, but getting the MOC from the app delegate is still ok.  One other thing - If you have tabs and you put your MOC in the root view controller, can you just imagine the kind of codes you need just to be able to address that instance of the MOC? ... and your risk of loosing data if you create another MOC in the other tab.

Comment: Huh? How are you risking losing data? Again, the managed object context is a *scratch pad of changes*. For example, a master view controller has one managed object context, the detail view controller has another. When the detail view controller edits a model object those changes only exist there until the context is saved. If you are using parent-child contexts (and you should be), the changes are not *persisted* until they are saved all the way up the chain to the store. This is how Core Data is *intended* to be used. It's primary value is change management.

Comment: From the Programming Guide: "You can think of a managed object context as an intelligent scratch pad. When you fetch objects from a persistent store, you bring temporary copies onto the scratch pad where they form an object graph (or a collection of object graphs). You can then modify those objects however you like. Unless you actually save those changes, however, the persistent store remains unaltered." Creating multiple contexts to manage changes and edits is mentioned extensively throughout the documentation - in the PG, in Core Data Snippets, and elsewhere.

Comment: How do you loose data or screw it up? -  I can have changes in the 2 MOCS that are logically related to each other, when I save one it will think that the changes in 1 of the MOCS does not exist. When I save the other MOC it will see the changes of the 1st MOC and disallow lets say a duplicate - at that point in time you are already in trouble.  Having 1 MOC ensures that all changes in 1 tab are seen in the other tab, even if the MOC is not yet saved. Your lecture about the MOC nature taken from Apple are all good but you fail to understand the implications.

Comment: The scenario you are describing is a merge conflict, and the problem you are describing is a result of using the wrong policy. Your two tabs scenario does not require a shared context - your contexts should be getting updates from the store and from other contexts using parent-child relationships or (if using thread confinement) notifications (see ``mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:``). Again, the documentation is quite explicit about this. Having deployed several widely used CoreData applications I am quite familiar with the "implications" of sharing a single context. Don't.

Comment: You are not the only one with a lot of Core data apps. Lets drop this - why don't yóu just ask apple why their templates for Core Data includes all those codes in the App delegate.  ....   Seems to me that your solution is making a mountain out of a mole hill, the 1 MOC works well and your arguments for multiple MOCs conflict with the apple advice to "pass the baton".  Come on - you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: I have talked to Apple engineers and DTS about the templates (and outdated concurrency guide), and have radars filed (14311048,14310971,14310970,14310967,14310964). Again, Apple's own documentation is counter to your statements. I would suggest reviewing the PG, Core Data Snippets, the release notes, the Incremental Store PG, and the "Core Data Best Practices" WWDC session.

Answer (score -1):

How about discarding the `if` statements in the view controllers?

If you start a new Xcode project using the "Empty Application" template and click the "use Core Data" checkbox, you'll see the required code in the app delegate to

- configure a PersistentStoreCoordinator
- load a ManagedObjectModel
- open a ManagedObjectContext

The default project template exposes those as properties on the AppDelegate, so you can refer to those elsewhere in the app like so

```
// note that you need to import the header to see the properties directly
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = myApp.managedObjectContext;
// use the moc as required....
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you've only got one method that's setting up the ManagedObjectContext, so there's only one place to look if it's not behaving as expected... no setting the moc to `nil` and then depending on an `if` statement to set it to a non-nil value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is actually an EXTREMELY poor example to follow. You should not be dumping things like this into the app delegate and accessing them that way. Apple's template *passes* that context from the application delegate into the view controller. Getting a managed object context from a delegate of the view controller is also a valid approach.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but I figured that if the OP knew how to set a symbolic breakpoint and debug the issue, he or she would have done so already. I'm not suggesting this is the One True Way to do it; I'm suggesting that this is a bodge that will get the OP past the issue. We all have to write a bunch of bad code before we can write good code; this is a piece of bad code that will let him or her move on to the next challenge.